# "I'm in" meaning?

Tags: spoken-english

I've seen these lines from the TV show Mom. **A** is a woman and **B** is a man

> A: So, should we do it?
>
> B: Yeah! Sure.
>
> A: Okay! Great! Tonight! Burgundy Bistro. 8:00 and I'll wear a red
>   scarf.
>
> B: I'll wear a Raiders cap.
>
> A: Well, the Niners would be better, but okay. Oh, wait, you're not
>   hiding a bald spot, are you?
>
> B: Are you kidding me? I've got the hair of three men.
>
> A: As long as it's on your head, **I'm in**.

In this context, it seems to me that "**I'm in**" is just like "**I'm fine**". Is that true? Does "**I'm in**" have other meanings colloquially?

Comment: I assume the "I'm in" part simply refers to the previous statement about the date at Burgundy Bistro and does not have a direct connection to the hair joke.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The expression "I'm in" or "count me in" mean that you wish to be included in a proposed activity.

For example:

> "I'm going to the bar. Anyone else coming?"
> "Count me in!"

I *believe* the expression may originate from gambling, possibly poker, or some other card game where players are dealt a hand and then decide whether they are playing on by saying that they are either "in" or "out". I'm unsure (sorry, I'm not really a gambler) but there may be other similar gambling expressions which mean that you wish to leave the game and for your winnings to be counted.

In your specific quote a man and a woman are making an arrangement to go out to a bistro/restaurant. The joke is that one guy says he has "the hair of three men", which *he* says to mean his hair is three-times as thick as most other men's hair, but the woman alludes to a possible second meaning. Personally, I assumed the second meaning was that he actually possesses some hair taken from three other men! But in comments below it has been pointed out a woman may be put off by body hair, and that she is talking about this. So she then adds a condition or caveat to his going out, which is that he will only go with him if he was talking about the hair on his head by saying "As long as it's on your head - I'm in!"

Comment: I haven't seen the show quoted in the OP, but it sounds like this is a man and woman planning a blind date, and the woman wants to clarify that the man is not hairy all over his body. Otherwise, I think something akin to, "As long as you mean that metaphorically..." would have been more appropriate.

Comment: "a second meaning which is that the first guy actually possesses some hair which he has taken from three other men." **What**? The phrase "As long as it's on your head" implies that the second meaning would be *body hair*, not the hair of other men!

Comment: @AlexandreAubrey Well, there's definitely duality of meaning implied! I considered that meaning, but why would him having thick body hair make his friend think twice about going out with him?

Comment: _See also_  [How many meanings does “I am in” have?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/288/how-many-meanings-does-i-am-in-have)

Answer (score 12):

In this context, "I'm in" means the same as "Count me in." That is, I want to be part of the group or activity.

https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=i%27m%20in

Comment: although you are correct, I wouldn't use urban dictionary as a source, because it is more of a humorous website with many non-serious definitions

Comment: Agreed, and I wouldn't normally use it either, but the top definitions are usually quite good, and it always focuses on colloquial use. Since this was a very specific colloquial phrase, I thought UD would be of more use than just one of many "in" definitions from a more official dictionary.