# How to express 3 people are coming tomorrow

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, american-english

Situation: This is a message I want to post to a group of 20 people mentioning:

> Anyone free tomorrow, let's plan to meet. name-1, name-2 and name-3 are in.

Does using the words "are in" here is correct? The intention is to convey that name-1, name-2 and name-3 people are coming to meet together, so if others wanna join, they can come too. Is this correct English? Any alternate ways of saying the same?

Comment: Of course, how could it be anything else but the plural? There are three people.

Comment: Yes, that would be understandable. You could also say _A, Band C are coming_.

Comment: Highly related: ["I'm in" meaning?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/171274/41273)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever there is concern about possible misunderstanding, say it differently.

In this case, rather than:

> name-1, name-2, and name-3 are in

which might make one wonder "are in *what?*", you could say:

> name-1, name-2, and name-3 will be there

but if that's too strong (e.g. it will be your fault if they don't all show up), try:

> name-1, name-2, and name-3 have said they will be there