# what do you mean when you say 'I am in' in this song?

Tags: expressions

> We're on course to follow You all our days
> Knowing, of course, that God is good always, always
> You know me, love me, I trust You with my life
> Your word, it shows me, a little bit more each day and every night
>
> With every twist, with every turn
> Jesus, You're my guide
> I will listen and I will learn
> Change my heart inside
> And help me bring glory to You, my King
> ***What I'm sayin' is, Jesus, I AM IN!***
>
> I'm gonna dance the dance, talk the talk
> Gonna live the life, gonna walk, walk, walk the walk

Comment: Hi! Welcome to ELL Stack Exchange!

Does this answer your question: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/288/how-many-meanings-does-i-am-in-have?

Comment: "I am in" or "I'm in" used as a stand-alone phrase means "I will join you" or "I am committed to this idea/plan/event/etc."

Comment: I am in = Count me in = Consider me to be (I am) a part of (in) what you're talking about.

Comment: Please provide the source.

Comment: Source seems to be "Jesus I Am in!" by Jana Alayra

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a clear question, just a lyric.  Please explain what your uncertainty is.

Comment: to be in [or into something: to like it or agree with it]=an idiomatic expression.